# Create a django project from an existing database

Tags: django, django-models

I have a n existing MySQL database. I want to create a new django application with that database.

I read that I need to run "syncdb" each and every time when add a new model in django. That time adding a new table in database in `<database_name>.<table_name>` format. And fetching data from that table.

What is the correct method to fetch data from an existing database in django ?

This is my model:

from django.db import models

```
class Users(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.employee_id
```

Comment: Was the existing database created by django?

Comment: no ... its not created by django. Its an existing php ( CI ) application

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Django model meta options to set `db_table` and `db_column` on your Models and Fields respectively. See these links for more info on how to use them:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column